# Replace ASCII / URI encoded characters in Hive to String

Tags: hive

I have some data in Hive that looks something like this -

```
select "showTitle=October01%2C2019%7C11PM&c3.video.isLive=T&Version=%2817888%29" as input;
```

I would like to replace all the URI encoded characters to their string equivalents. For example, `%2C` means a comma `,`. `%28` means an opening bracket `(` , `%29` means a closing bracket `)` and so on.

Can I do this with **regexp_replace()** function ?

The final output would be

```
showTitle=October01,2019|11PM&c3.video.isLive=T&Version=(17888)
```

The reference for ASCII encoding is here - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflect function to use "java.net.URLDecoder

```
SELECT reflect("java.net.URLDecoder", "decode", input, "UTF-8") 
from input_table
```

Here's [a link](http://bigdatums.net/2016/11/13/how-to-decode-urls-in-hive/) you can also follow to build HiveUDF (if you want)